# Get Command Prompt Window Content After Command Completion

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

I'm looking to get the content of a command prompt window after the completion of a command in C#.

Specifically, in this instance, I'm issuing a ping command from a button click and want to display the output in a textbox.

The code I'm using currently is:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.Arguments = "ping 192.168.1.254";
Process pingIt = Process.Start(startInfo);
string errors = pingIt.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
string output = pingIt.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

txtLog.Text = "";
if (errors != "")
{
    txtLog.Text = errors;
}
else
{
    txtLog.Text = output;
}
```

And it works, sort of. It grabs at least some output and displays it, but the ping itself doesn't execute - or at least this is what I assume given the output below and the command prompt window flashes for a brief second.

**Output:**

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Checkout\PingUtility\PingUtility\bin\Debug>

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
info.Arguments = "/C ping 127.0.0.1"; 
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
info.CreateNoWindow = true; 
info.FileName = "cmd.exe"; 
info.UseShellExecute = false; 
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
using (Process process = Process.Start(info)) 
{ 
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput) 
    { 
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
        textBox1.Text += result; 
    } 
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Ah that's perfect! I was at least kind of along the right lines. Thanks!